# Remove space between digits without gluing separate float numbers together in R

Tags: r

I need to remove the space between the digits in a number.
Currently I have: *"......                                                                              36 191        39 128       ......                                                                  10            (17)          -"*.
And I need to get the following: *"......                                                                           36191        39128       ......                                                                  10            (17)          -"*.
I would be grateful for any help in this regard.

Comment: What do you have to reliably tell the difference between spaces that should be eliminated vs. those that should be kept?  Is it always 2 digits followed by 3 that should be combined? Or every other space?

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions if you want to avoid dependencies, but this is made easy with the `stringr` package.

```
library(stringr)
x_string <- " 36 191 39 128 10 (17)"
str_replace_all(x_string, " ", "")
# [1] "361913912810(17)"
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to extract '36191' and '39128' as two separate numbers and ignore the rest.

Comment: That wasn't in the original question and I don't know what you mean "two separate numbers." You need to give us what you have and the result you expect.